Instatiated Prefab does not move
I am learning Unity.
I made a pine prefab. (Igaguri means a pine in Japanese.)
These are the code.

IgaguriController.cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class IgaguriController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Shoot(Vector3 dir)
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(dir); //*2
    }
    void Start()
    {
        Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
        //Shoot(new Vector3(0, 200, 2000));
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
        GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();
    }
}


IgaguriGenerator.cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class IgaguriGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject igaguriPrefab;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            GameObject igaguri =  Instantiate(igaguriPrefab);//*1
            igaguri.GetComponent<IgaguriController>().Shoot(new Vector3(0, 200, 2000));
        }
    }
}

I put a break point the line with "//*1" and "//*2".
Then,the code properly works.
However, the Game window shows a pine which does not move.
In other words, an instantiated pine just stays an initial position.
I am happy if you give me any tips to solve this problem.
Thank you for reading.



I debug by myself but I could not find the bug.

 GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true; will stop force applying to it

Do you mean you can't move the prefab using transform components in the editor, or you want to move it at runtime? Have you checked its rigid body settings?

It looks like the Prefab also has isKinematic = checked. You need to uncheck it in the prefab too

Your image indicates that Rigidbody's Kinematic is already checked. Please ensure that it is unchecked in the inspector or add GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true; to the Start function.
And it's better if you adding validation to your OnCollisionEnter function to ensure that the pine stops only when colliding with a specific object. For example:
if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Target") {
    // Stop the pine movement
}

